# Alternative to multiple if statements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This just feels inefficient and ugly:

```
if(foo("val1")) {
    let val1 = foo("val1")
}

if(foo("val2")) {
    let val2 = foo("val2")
}

/* more IFs */

if(foo("val13")) {
    let val13 = foo("val13")
}
```

What would be a good way to avoid all these ifs?

Edit: The strings are not actually called Val1 ... val13 (I used it as an example, might have been confusing, sorry).

Comment: What will you put in `valXX` if `foo("valXX")` is false? Anything?

Comment: Side note: `let` is block-scoped, so you probably want to declare those outside the `if` unless you're really using them only in the `if` block.

Comment: @Hevar I don't see here any `React` related code.

Comment: Have you considered using an array?

Comment: What's the point of having 13 variables named `val1`, ..., `val13`?

Comment: @Oriol they are not actually named like that, I just used that as an example for simplicity. But it might not have worked out that way, and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: just `var vals1=foo("val1"), vals2=foo("val2"), ... etc` ... and have foo return `undefined` or a value ... cuts down the number of times you call foo(x)

Comment: @AlexanderT. Yeah, you're right. Been working in a React project so its was just a reflex I added React too. I've removed the React tag now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just briefly but wasn't sure if that was the most efficient way so I asked to know for sure.

Comment: What about using switch case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, I'd probably use an array and a loop:

```
let vals = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 13; ++i) {
    let name = "val" + i;
    if (foo(name)) {
        vals[i - 1] = foo(name);
    }
}
```

Note that if you assign to a later index without assigning to an earlier one, you end up with a *sparse* array. E.g.:

```
let a = [];
a[2] = "two";
```

...`a` has no entries for 0 or 1 *at all*. (Accessing them will give you the value `undefined`, though.)

Comment: So something similar to `const values = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'].map(foo)`would also work out?

Comment: @Hevar that would have been my suggestion - it reads a lot better than generating values like this, which takes your question a little too literallly I think

Comment: @Hevar: That does something different from what's in your question (and relies on `foo` only paying attention to its first argument), but of course could well work for what you're trying to do. You haven't told us what you're actually trying to do, so...